# update fields with inner values

Tags: json, jq

I have a json string like:

```
    {
        "name" : "test",
        "properties": {
            "p2": {"test": "test", "value": "b"},
            "p1": {"value": "a"},
            "p3": {"value": "c"}
        }
    }
```

and I want:

```
{
"p2" : "b",
"p1" : "a",
"p3" : "c"
}
```

and the order doesn't matter, but the relation of keys and values must be the same as origin.

I tried
`jq '.properties | (keys_unsorted, .[].value)'` and it gives:

```
[
  "p2",
  "p1",
  "p3"
]
"b"
"a"
"c"
```

then I split the command into `jq '.properties | keys_unsorted'` and `jq '.properties | .[].value'`, do some editing by hands, and use `paste` command to join the results.

Does a more reasonable way exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`map_values`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#map(x),map_values(x)).

```
$ jq '.properties | map_values(.value)' file
{
  "p2": "b",
  "p1": "a",
  "p3": "c"
}
```